# SQL Server for xml raw dynamic row name

Tags: sql, sql-server

The select:

`select top 2 name, crdate from sys.sysobjects where xtype = 'u' for xml raw('object')`


 produces a result similar to this

```
<object name="table_name1" crdate="2010-05-03T09:34:08.150" />
<object name="table_name2" crdate="2011-04-17T11:19:18.157" />
```

Is there any way to put a variable (like @RowName) in place of the word "object"?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
declare @s nvarchar(4000)
select @s ='select top 2 name, crdate from sys.sysobjects where xtype = ''u'' for xml raw('''+@rowname+''')'
exec sp_executesql @s
```

Comment: If this command is executed in a Stored Procedure, it does not generate a performance hit?

Comment: Very minimal, I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @xml.modify('declare default element namespace "http://www.someurl.com";
                     insert <root>root> ');

set @xml.modify('insert <child1><test1></test1></child1> as last into (/*:root)[1]');   
set @xml.modify('insert <child2><test2></test2></child2> as last into (/*:Root[1]/*:Child1[1])');
```

Comment: This is how multiple xml elements can be implemented